# How to override the properties of a CSS class to avoid copying and renaming styles

Tags: css, class, overriding

I am fairly new to CSS3 and I want to be able to do the following:

When I add a class into a an element, it overrides the properties of another class used in this specific element.

Let's say that I have

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
```

I want to be able to add a class called `bakground-none`, that will over override the default background in the class `left`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 124):

There are different ways in which properties can be overridden. Assuming you have

```
.left { background: blue }
```

e.g. any of the following would override it:

```
a.background-none { background: none; }
body .background-none { background: none; }
.background-none { background: none !important; }
```

The first two “win” by selector specificity; the third one wins by `!important`, a blunt instrument.

You could also organize your style sheets so that e.g. the rule

```
.background-none { background: none; }
```

wins simply by order, i.e. by being *after* an otherwise equally “powerful” rule. But this imposes restrictions and requires you to be careful in any reorganization of style sheets.

These are all examples of the [CSS Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), a crucial but widely misunderstood concept. It defines the exact rules for resolving conflicts between style sheet rules.

P.S. I used `left` and `background-none` as they were used in the question. They are examples of class names that should *not* be used, since they reflect specific rendering and not structural or semantic roles.

Comment: You wrote *They are examples of class names that should not be used, since they reflect specific rendering and not structural or semantic roles.* Could you elaborate, please? Why should `left` and `background-none` be avoided?

Comment: @Socrates: Some folks feel that css classes should only be given names that identify what the element it is being applied to is or does (e.g. `button`, `name-label`, etc.). Others feel that CSS becomes unmanageable if you use this approach and you should use "utility-first" or "functional" css where classes correspond to property values (e.g. `margin-top-4`, `width-10`, etc.). Historically the "semantic" approach has been dominant while recently the "functional" approach has been gaining adherents. Try both on a medium sized project and then decide for yourself which is superior.

Comment: didnt know about !important, thanks

Answer (score 77):

Just use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) it will help to override

```
background:none !important;
```

Although it is said to be a bad practice, `!important` can be useful for utility classes, you just need to use it responsibly, check this: [**When Using important is the right choice**](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: !important is a bad practice. Soon, all code becomes !important.

Answer (score 45):

You should override by increasing **Specificity** of your styling. There are different ways of increasing the Specificity. Usage of `!important` which effects specificity, is a **bad practice** because it breaks natural cascading in your style sheet.

Following diagram taken from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) will help you produce right specificity for your element based on a points structure. Whichever specificity has higher points, will win. Sounds like a game - doesn't it?

[image]

Checkout sample calculations here on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). This will help you understand the concept very well and it will only take 2 minutes.

If you then like to produce and/or compare different specificities by yourself, try this Specificity Calculator: https://specificity.keegan.st/ or you can just use traditional paper/pencil.

For further reading try [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

All the best for not using `!important`.

Answer (score 33):

As an alternative to the `important` keyword, you could make the selector more specific,
for example:

```
.left.background-none { background:none; }
```

(Note: no space between the class names).

In this case, the rule will apply when both `.left` and `.background-none` are listed in the class attribute (regardless of the order or proximity).

Answer (score 10):

If you list the `bakground-none` class after the other classes, its properties will override those already set. There is no need to use `!important` here.

For example:

```
.red { background-color: red; }
.background-none { background: none; }
```

and

```
<a class="red background-none" href="#carousel">...</a>
```

The link will not have a red background. Please note that this only overrides properties that have a selector that is less or equally specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this as a first solution, but for some reason it didn't work!

Comment: This way of overriding css classes will not work if the styles are defines in a specific way like .form-horizontal .form-group{margin-left:-15px}. Here you'll have to use !important

Comment: add !important to .background-none { background: none !importatn; } this works fine

Answer (score 2):

LIFO is the way browser parses CSS properties..If you are using Sass declare a variable called as

> "$header-background: red;"

use it instead of directly assigning values like red or blue.
When you want to override just reassign the value to

> "$header-background:blue"

then

> background-color:$header-background;

it should smoothly override. Using "!important" is not always the right choice..Its just a hotfix