# Can we use our background in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how to use our background in bootstrap?
I use Bootsnip site to make my site, but I have to make my site with white background;

Can we use our background in bootstrap?
Thank you;

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the 'background-color' attribute of the html `body`. The color that you are seeing now is defined in one of the minified CSS files you have downloaded. You can override that property to set it to white or a color of your liking. More info: [How to override the properties of a CSS class using another CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954715/how-to-override-the-properties-of-a-css-class-using-another-css-class)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you need to create a css rule and use the `background-color:` you can also add a image by using `background-image:`

Worth looking up some of these as they will prove very helpful