# How to make a bitcoin widget full width?

Tags: css, widget, bitcoin

I'm trying to embed the bitcoin widget headlines from www.bitcoin.com into my website but is there a way to make it full-width?

here is the widget (taking out the divs to be able to show it here):

div class="btcwdgt-news" bw-entries="3" bw-theme="light"

I'd like it to occupy the whole width of my page if possible.

(original link: bitcoin.com/widgets)

Comment: Could I edit the css at all in a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the widget CSS parameters by inserting in you CSS file the following:

```
div.btcwdgt {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Also I would recommend you to read this: [How to override the properties of a CSS class using another CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954715/how-to-override-the-properties-of-a-css-class-using-another-css-class)

```js
(function(b,i,t,C,O,I,N) {
    window.addEventListener('load',function() {
      if(b.getElementById(C))return;
      I=b.createElement(i),N=b.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      I.src=t;I.id=C;N.parentNode.insertBefore(I, N);
    },false)
  })(document,'script','https://widgets.bitcoin.com/widget.js','btcwdgt');
```

```css
div.btcwdgt {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="btcwdgt-news" bw-entries="3" bw-theme="light"></div>
```

Comment: If it works for your, mark this answer as the right answer... See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers