# How can I override classes with JSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jss

My component library has some out-of-the-box components that are going to require me to do some overrides. I am trying to avoid using traditional CSS or SASS, but i'm not sure how you can do class overrides in **JSS**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override the properties of a CSS class using another CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954715/how-to-override-the-properties-of-a-css-class-using-another-css-class)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am trying to do this in JSS, not CSS

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you have a demo somewhere?

Comment: Sure, I mean...Just something simple like this... Here's what my code compiles to..

`<div class="MuiListItemText-root-262 />`

I want to be able to target that specific item like this 

`const styles = () => {
     MultiListItemText-root-262: {
          color: red;
}
}`

Comment: did you manage to achieve this? @ChristopherMellor, I get the impression that your question was missunderstood

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic implementation. I first look up the DOM element and then change the className property of it. However, there are multiple ways of achieving this and not one is necesarrily better than another.

```js
function change () {
  
let el = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

el[0].className = "foo";
}
```

```css
.bar {
    background-color: red;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
aefreawafeawef
</div>
 <button onclick="change()">change class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only add the classList.

```js
function change () {
  
let el = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

el[0].classList.add("foo");
}
```

```css
.bar {
    background-color: red;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
aefreawafeawef
</div>
 <button onclick="change()">change class</button>
```