# Overwrite parent CSS table class

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if you can help me understand how to overwrite parent CSS classes. I have the main CSS generically defined on a table, td and thead levels, which currently says that all tables should be width="100%"

I want to have a new table where it takes the minimum width it can (i.e. shrinks to size/content) - could you help me understand how can it be done?

Thank yoU!

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20955958/4400533) answer please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override the properties of a CSS class using another CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954715/how-to-override-the-properties-of-a-css-class-using-another-css-class)

Comment: To ask a proper question you should add a relevant code snippet of what you have tried. Now we have to quess the CSS and HTML structure