# Thymeleaf Input Form Binding

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

i have a form that binded to my class and everything works fine.

```
<form th:action="@{/createPost}" th:object="${newPost}" method="post" class="form-signin">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{topic}" class="new-post-topic-input" placeholder="post topic"
               autofocus="true"/>
</form>
```

I want to change my input css to a different style, but type='text' overwrites everything. But if i change input type to anything else, it doesn't bind values.
Can i make thymeleaf see other input types to bind them?

**UPDATE**

i have bootstrap css file that contains css style for

But i want to have my own style for this input without deleting bootstrap css from page. But if i add class='anyClass' to this input, css from  bootstrap from type='text' overwrites everything. And if i change type from text to anything else, thymeleaf doesn't map values anymore.

**upd2**
MY QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT CSS OVERRRIDING.

My question is about thymeleaf data object binding. I have th:object="${newPost}"
in the form tag. Thymeleaf sees it and when i submit my form, it binds every ,  to fields of this object.

BUT if i change from type='text' to type='ANYTHING ELSE'> thymeleaf doesn't map anything. How can i make thymeleaf bind other tags like  etc. To my object?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you want to change via CSS? What does `type='text'` overwrite? What has *input CSS* to do with the type of `input`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override the properties of a CSS class using another CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954715/how-to-override-the-properties-of-a-css-class-using-another-css-class)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with a description of what is not working as expected. It is not very helpfull if you talk about CSS styling when it has nothing to do with your problem.

[The docu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) clearly says it is possible to bind to other types:

> Note that `th:field` also understands the new types of `<input>` element introduced by HTML5 like `<input type="datetime" ... />`, `<input type="color" ... />`, etc., effectively adding complete HTML5 support to Spring MVC.

The documentation also provides an example:

```
<div>
  <label th:for="${#ids.next('covered')}" th:text="#{seedstarter.covered}">Covered</label>
  <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{covered}" />
</div>
```

The field `covered` has to be of type `boolean` then of course. Please make sure the type of your `input` element matches the type of your field.

Comment: so basically it understand basic types, but not my types.

Comment: I can not answer that because I do not know what 'your' types are.